Does angular absement exist?
Probably a dumb question. I'm a highschool student, and I don't even know if it is even possible to integrate an angle (for reference, I haven't even learnt integration yet at school, my calculus knowledge extends to differentiation for now).
Absement is the area under the curve for a displacement-time graph. So angular absement is the integral of angular displacement.
If it does, what about angular absity, angular abseleration, etc.

Of course you can integrate over an angle. Indeed, many more functions can be integrated than can be differentiated, so from a mathematical perspective, everything should work. The issue with what you are proposing is that after a full rotation, the system returns to its initial position, so you would need to account for that somehow.

Yes. A simple example - we know that the length of an arc of a circle with radius $r$ and angular length $d\theta$ (in radians) is $r\space d\theta$. So the area of of a small segment with radial length $dr$ and angular length $d\theta$ is $r\space dr\space d\theta$. If we integrate this from $r=0$ to $r=R$ we get
$\displaystyle \left( \int_0^R r\space dr\space \right) d\theta = \frac {R^2} 2 \space d\theta$
If we take a point that is moving in a circle of radius $R$ with constant angular velocity $\omega$ radians per second then in time $dt$ it moves through an angle $d\theta = \omega \space dt$ and so traces out a segment of area $\omega \frac {R^2} 2 \space dt$. It takes time $\frac {2 \pi}{\omega}$ to complete one revolution, so the total area inside the circle is
$\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac {2\pi}{\omega}} \omega \frac {R^2} 2 \space dt = \pi R^2$
which gives us an expression for the area of a circle.

But this is not absement. The equivalent of angular absement would be an integration like $\int \theta(t) dt$. This is just an integral over a differential angular element.

@agaminon To find an area you need an expression of the form $\int r(t) \theta(t) dt$. In my example you can just replace $d\theta$ by $\omega \space dt$ and reach the same result. I have amended my answer.

In principle yes, it exists. If an object moves around some axis such that its displacement can be defined through an angular coordinate $\theta(t$), the angular absement would just be
$$A = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\theta(t) dt .$$
Now this definition has dimensions of $\mathrm{T}$, while regular absement has dimensions $\mathrm{L\cdot T}$. There are many ways you could change this if you want equivalent units. If the motion has a fixed radius, you could just multiply by the radius as the angular displacement is just $R\theta(t)$. For motion with a non constant radius, you would integrate the time dependent angular displacement $R(t)\theta(t)$.
